# CRA Workbox customize stored cache name

Tags: reactjs, service, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I have a **CRA** and I m **using service workers**. I created a custom service worker in `public` folder and I append it with `cra-append-sw`. There I added an "activate" event where I clear all cache like so :

```
self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((names) => {
      for (let cacheName of names) {
           caches.delete(cacheName);
      }
    })
  );
});
```

The thing is, in storage there is a default key created by `Workbox`. Is it possible to change that default name and add my own version name?
Another thing that it's weird to me is that if I leave that code snippet like that, once I install the new worker with `skipWaiting()` I still have the same default key in storage but once the new worker took over, it doesn't seem to cache files. I refreshed the page and that cache key name has nothing in it. Only if I comment out "activate" event and I `skpiWait()` the new updated worker then it starts caching again.